# How can I create a ParseUser from an already logged in Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have an android app that already have a Facebook login using the Facebook SDK.
Now, I would like to take the already logged-in user and create a ParseUser for it.

I tried a few approaches and failed with each and every one of them (like become and linkace).

Can you please help out? I couldn't find anything in the docs too. it was always referring to the case when I'll use Parse's Facebook login avtivity...

Thanks,
Nimrod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, After a while digging in... I'm pretty sure it's not possible.
I suggest the Parse team to add this feature as it will make existing apps migration to Parse easier.